# Trying to plot coordinates through xy data, but ArcMap plots the points in the Atlantic ocean near 0 degrees by 0 degrees every time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

No matter what I do when trying to plot these XY data points it is always plotted in the Atlantic ocean, basically the south of Ghana every time. I've attempted exporting the .csv file, and .xlsx file, but no luck. The points are all in the same county at roughly 38, -95. I'm using the World Topographic base map along with a shape file of county boundaries in the US that align perfectly.

Comment: How are you entering the coordinates?  X/Y = Long/Lat (eg Y = 38, X = -95 in your example)

Comment: I've been using X/Y = Long/Lat however I've tried both. They both end up near 0 degrees 0 degrees, but it seems like the points are now turned 90 degrees.

Comment: Again, how are you entering the coordinates?  What is your process to get them into ArcMap?

Comment: What CRS are you using? Geographic coordinates require a geographic CRS. Again as @Midavalo says, how are you entering the points? If you have a table with a header *Create feature class from XY table* springs to mind https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/databases/create-a-feature-class-in-a-database-in-arcgis.htm but Excel and CSV are known to be really problematic, convert to a different table format first (dBase .dbf or file/personal geodatabase table) that is more rigid in its types.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that ArcMap is interpreting your coordinates as Meters, rather than Degrees.  If you Identify one of the points you may see this reflected as such

[image]

[image]

The reason for this is beause the World Topographic Basemap comes in with a Coordinate System `WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere` with a linear unit of meters - `Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)`

[image]

When you load your points from coordinates try to define a coordinate system that matches your coordinates.  For example if I use the Geographic Coordinate System `WGS 1984` for my points they end up roughly in Kansas/Missouri area

[image]

Answer (score -2):

go to table of content
right click layers
go to coordinate system
the layer's coordinate system and shapefiles/csv coordinate system must be same
try it if it isn't working let me know

also check you have added data correctly while adding xy data
x(long)
y(lat)
thanks